# Approximation Methods for non-convex functions of three variables?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-approximation

Let $f(x,y,z) = xyz$ be a function of three variables where $x>0,z>0$ and $y\in[0,1]$. For a function of two variables i.e., $f(x,y) = xy$, the approximation is given as:

$f(x,y) = (x+y)^2 -(x^2 + y^2)$

The above function is a difference of convex and concave function which will be eventually solved using CCP. How can the above analogy be extended to a function of three variables?

Comment: Any quadratic function of $n$ variables can easily be written as the difference of convex functions (just split the positive and negative eigenvalues.)  What's your particular quadratic function of 3 variables?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The function is the one that i wrote in the question i.e., $f(x,y,z)=xyz$

Comment: So you're looking to write $f(x,y,z)=xyz$ as a difference of convex functions?  You'll need to go to something higher order than quadratic.

Comment: Yes. Because i would like to convert the function into a convex form so that it can be solved using MATLAB cvx toolbox.

Comment: Have you tried starting by expanding $(x+y+z)^{3}$ and then finding ways to express each term in DC form and subtracting off all terms but the $xyz$?

Comment: I have tried it but could not get an appropriate form

Comment: You'd need to do similar formulas for $f(x,y,z)=x^{2}y$, etc.